# How to use L2 normalization on features before using them in SVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training SVM with features extracted from Convolutional Neural Network. As written in this paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3531v4.pdf) it is good to L2-normalize your features before applying SVM on them.

I use this function to normalize vectors:

```
def l2normalize(features):
    l2norm = np.sum(np.abs(features)**2,axis=-1)**(1./2)
    return features/l2norm
```

After this normalization my accuracy drops from around 60% to 20% so something is clearly wrong. How should I properly prepare my vectors for SVM with L2 norm?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are actually normalizing **both** the features extracted from training data and the test data.
2. Try using `normalize` from `sklearn.preprocessing`. I checked and your function returns slightly different values.